# Julia plotting in 3D: How to draw a line between coordinates?

Tags: julia

I am working on a program that a friend wrote in Julia. We have to do some work for university, especially for a course called "dynamic modelling".

The thing is to reproduce some great work of Kashtan and Alon; maybe you know their publication about biological networks and genetic algorithms. Now my friend asked me to find out, whether we can plot something in 3D and I don't know how to do that. He gave me some part of our program (see code below) and wrote me to find out, whether we can draw a line from one coordinate (x,y,z) to another coordinate (x,y,z). Do you know how to do that in Julia?

```
 module ShowGateNet

export
    showGate,
    setGattaStruct;

using Plots;
using BPIPopulation;

abstract GrafGate

type GGate <: GrafGate
    in1::Array{Integer};
    in2::Array{Integer};
    out::Array{Integer};
end;

#---------------------------------------------------------------
# creates a 2D-matrix for almost a circle:
# mx:: x-coordinate of the center circle
# my:: y-coordinate of the center circle
#  r:: radius of the circle
#---------------------------------------------------------------
 function circNumba(rx=2::Integer,cx=0::Integer,cy=0::Integer, cz=0)
   k=0:360;
   c=zeros(length(k),4);
   c[:,1] = k;
   c[:,2] = round(cos(radian(k))*rx+cx,3);
   c[:,3] = cy;
    c[:,4] = round(sin(radian(k))*rx+cz,3);
   return c;     
 end;


function radian(grad) 
   return round(2*pi*grad/360,3);
end

function showGate(cx,cy,cz,numba)
    r = 2;
    centr = [cx;cy;cz];
    # A = [centr[1]-1;centr[2];centr[3]];
    # B = [centr[1];centr[2]+1;centr[3]];
    C = [centr[1];centr[2]-1;centr[3]];
    in2 = [centr[1]-3;centr[2]+1;centr[3]-1];
    in1 = [centr[1]+3;centr[2]-1;centr[3]-1];
    K = [centr[1];centr[2];centr[3]-1];
    O = [centr[1];centr[2];centr[3]-3];
    kCirc = circNumba(r,K[1],K[2],K[3]);
    #display(plot!(kCirc[:,2],kCirc[:,3],kCirc[:,4],title="test-circ",line=3,color="red",zlabel="Z",xlabel="X",ylabel="Y"));
    #display(plot!([centr[1],centr[1],centr[1]],[centr[2],centr[2],centr[2]],[centr[3]-1-r,centr[3]-1-r,centr[3]-3-r],w=3,color="blue"));
    #display(plot!([centr[1]-3,centr[1]-3,centr[1]-2],[centr[2],centr[2],centr[2]],[centr[3],centr[3],centr[3]]-1,w=3,color="green")); #A nach K
    #display(plot!([centr[1]+2,centr[1]+2,centr[1]+3],[centr[2],centr[2],centr[2]],[centr[3],centr[3],centr[3]]-1,w=3,color="green")); #A nach K    
    display(plot(kCirc[:,2],kCirc[:,3],kCirc[:,4],title="test-circ",line=3,color="red",zlabel="Z",xlabel="X",ylabel="Y"));
    plot!([centr[1],centr[1],centr[1]],[centr[2],centr[2],centr[2]],[centr[3]-1-r,centr[3]-1-r,centr[3]-3-r],w=3,color="blue");#senkrechte
    plot!([centr[1]-3,centr[1]-3,centr[1]-2],[centr[2],centr[2],centr[2]],[centr[3],centr[3],centr[3]]-1,w=3,color="green"); #A nach K
    plot!([centr[1]+2,centr[1]+2,centr[1]+3],[centr[2],centr[2],centr[2]],[centr[3],centr[3],centr[3]]-1,w=3,color="green"); #A nach K
    plotNumba(K,numba);
end;

function showGate2(cx,cy,cz,numba)
    r = 2;
    centr = [cx;cy;cz];
    # A = [centr[1]-1;centr[2];centr[3]];
    # B = [centr[1];centr[2]+1;centr[3]];
    C = [centr[1];centr[2]-1;centr[3]];
    in2 = [centr[1]+1;centr[2]+1;centr[3]];
    in1 = [centr[1]+1;centr[2]-1;centr[3]];
    K = [centr[1];centr[2]-r*2;centr[3]-1];
    O = [centr[1];centr[2];centr[3]-1];
    kCirc = circNumba(r,K[1],K[2],K[3]);
    display(plot(kCirc[:,2],kCirc[:,3],kCirc[:,4],title="test-circ",line=3,color="red",zlabel="Z",xlabel="X",ylabel="Y"));
    plot!([centr[1],centr[1],centr[1]],[centr[2],centr[2],centr[2]],[centr[3]-1-r,centr[3]-1-r,centr[3]-3-r],w=3,color="blue");
    plotNumba(K,numba);
end;


function showGate2!(cx,cy,cz,numba)
    r = 2;
    centr = [cx;cy;cz];
    # A = [centr[1]-1;centr[2];centr[3]];
    # B = [centr[1];centr[2]+1;centr[3]];
    C = [centr[1];centr[2]-1;centr[3]];
    in2 = [centr[1]+1;centr[2]+1;centr[3]];
    in1 = [centr[1]+1;centr[2]-1;centr[3]];
    K = [centr[1];centr[2];centr[3]-1];
    O = [centr[1];centr[2];centr[3]-1];
    kCirc = circNumba(r,K[1],K[2],K[3]);
    plot!(kCirc[:,2],kCirc[:,3],kCirc[:,4],title="test-circ",line=3,color="red",zlabel="Z",xlabel="X",ylabel="Y");
    plot!([centr[1],centr[1],centr[1]],[centr[2],centr[2],centr[2]],[centr[3]-1-r,centr[3]-1-r,centr[3]-3-r],w=3,color="blue");
    plot!([centr[1]-3,centr[1]-3,centr[1]-2],[centr[2],centr[2],centr[2]],[centr[3],centr[3],centr[3]]-1,w=3,color="green"); #A nach K
    plot!([centr[1]+2,centr[1]+2,centr[1]+3],[centr[2],centr[2],centr[2]],[centr[3],centr[3],centr[3]]-1,w=3,color="green"); #A nach K
    plotNumba(K,numba);
end;

function showGateIn!(cx,cy,cz,numba)
    r = 2;
    centr = [cx;cy;cz];
    # A = [centr[1]-1;centr[2];centr[3]];
    # B = [centr[1];centr[2]+1;centr[3]];
    C = [centr[1];centr[2]-1;centr[3]];
    in2 = [centr[1]+1;centr[2]+1;centr[3]];
    in1 = [centr[1]+1;centr[2]-1;centr[3]];
    K = [centr[1];centr[2];centr[3]-1];
    O = [centr[1];centr[2];centr[3]-1];
    kCirc = circNumba(r,K[1],K[2],K[3]);
    plot!(kCirc[:,2],kCirc[:,3],kCirc[:,4],title="test-circ",line=3,color="red",zlabel="Z",xlabel="X",ylabel="Y");
    if numba == 1
        display(plot!([centr[1],centr[1],centr[1]],[centr[2],centr[2],centr[2]],[centr[3]-1-r,centr[3]-1-r,centr[3]-3-r],w=3,color="blue"));
    else
        plot!([centr[1],centr[1],centr[1]],[centr[2],centr[2],centr[2]],[centr[3]-1-r,centr[3]-1-r,centr[3]-3-r],w=3,color="blue");
    end;
    plotNumba(K,numba);
end;



function showGateL!(cx,cy,cz,numba)
    r = 2;
    centr = [cx;cy;cz];
    # A = [centr[1]-1;centr[2];centr[3]];
    # B = [centr[1];centr[2]+1;centr[3]];
    C = [centr[1];centr[2]-1;centr[3]];
    in2 = [centr[1]+1;centr[2]+1;centr[3]];
    in1 = [centr[1]+1;centr[2]-1;centr[3]];
    K = [centr[1]-1-r;centr[2];centr[3]-1];
    O = [centr[1];centr[2];centr[3]-1];
    kCirc = circNumba(r,K[1],K[2],K[3]);
    plot!(kCirc[:,2],kCirc[:,3],kCirc[:,4],title="test-circ",line=3,color="red");
    plot!([centr[1]-1,centr[1]-1,centr[1]],[centr[2],centr[2],centr[2]],[centr[3],centr[3],centr[3]]-1,w=3,color="green"); #A nach K
    plot!([centr[1],centr[1],centr[1]+1],[centr[2],centr[2],centr[2]]+0.5,[centr[3]-1,centr[3]-1,centr[3]-1],w=3,color="green");# B nach D
    plot!([centr[1],centr[1],centr[1]+1],[centr[2],centr[2],centr[2]]-0.5,[centr[3],centr[3],centr[3]]-1,w=3,color="green");# C nach E
    plot!([centr[1],centr[1],centr[1]],[centr[2]-0.5,centr[2]-0.5,centr[2]+0.5],[centr[3],centr[3],centr[3]]-1,w=3,color="green"); # C nach B (waagerechte
    plot!([centr[1],centr[1],centr[1]],[centr[2],centr[2],centr[2]],[centr[3]-1,centr[3]-1,centr[3]-3],w=3,color="blue");
    plotNumba(K,numba);
end;

function showGateR!(cx,cy,cz,numba)
    r = 2;
    centr = [cx;cy;cz];
    # A = [centr[1]-1;centr[2];centr[3]];
    # B = [centr[1];centr[2]+1;centr[3]];
    C = [centr[1];centr[2]-1;centr[3]];
    in2 = [centr[1]+1;centr[2]+1;centr[3]];
    in1 = [centr[1]+1;centr[2]-1;centr[3]];
    K = [centr[1]+1+r;centr[2];centr[3]-1];
    O = [centr[1];centr[2];centr[3]-1];
    kCirc = circNumba(r,K[1],K[2],K[3]);
    plot!(kCirc[:,2],kCirc[:,3],kCirc[:,4],title="test-circ",line=3,color="red");
    plot!([centr[1]+1,centr[1]+1,centr[1]],[centr[2],centr[2],centr[2]],[centr[3],centr[3],centr[3]]-1,w=3,color="green"); #A nach K
    plot!([centr[1],centr[1],centr[1]-1],[centr[2],centr[2],centr[2]]+0.5,[centr[3]-1,centr[3]-1,centr[3]-1],w=3,color="green");# B nach D
    plot!([centr[1],centr[1],centr[1]-1],[centr[2],centr[2],centr[2]]-0.5,[centr[3],centr[3],centr[3]]-1,w=3,color="green");# C nach E
    plot!([centr[1],centr[1],centr[1]],[centr[2]-0.5,centr[2]-0.5,centr[2]+0.5],[centr[3],centr[3],centr[3]]-1,w=3,color="green"); # C nach B (waagerechte
    plot!([centr[1],centr[1],centr[1]],[centr[2],centr[2],centr[2]],[centr[3]-1,centr[3]-1,centr[3]-3],w=3,color="blue");
    plotNumba(K,numba);
end;

#function setGattaStruct(pEle::BPIPopulation.popElement)
function setGattaStruct()   
    showGate(0,0,-4,15);  # 15
    showGate2!(-4,0,8,14); #14
    showGate2!(4,0,8,13);   #13
    showGateL!(-8,4,16,12); #12
    showGateL!(-8,-4,16,11); #11
    showGateR!(8,4,16,10); #10
    showGateR!(8,-4,16,9); #9
    showGateL!(-8,4, 32,8); #8
    showGateL!(-8,-4, 32,7); #7
    showGateR!(8,4, 32,6); #6
    showGateR!(8,-4, 32,5); #5
    showGateIn!(0,6, 40,4); #4
    showGateIn!(0,2, 40,3); #3
    showGateIn!(0,-2, 40,2);    #2
    showGateIn!(0,-6, 40,1);    #1
    # hier dann evtl "PLOTTEN "der verbindungen 

end;


function plotNumba(K,numba)
    if numba>=10
        plot!([K[1],K[1],K[1]]-0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],
            [K[3]-1,K[3]-1,K[3]-3]+2,w=3,color="blue"); 
    end;    
    if numba%10 == 0
        plot!([K[1],K[1],K[1]]+1.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],
            [K[3]-1,K[3]-1,K[3]-3]+2,w=3,color="blue"); 
        plot!([K[1],K[1],K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],
            [K[3]-1,K[3]-1,K[3]-3]+2,w=3,color="blue"); 
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],
            [K[3],K[3],K[3]]-1,w=3,color="blue"); 
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],
            [K[3],K[3],K[3]]+1,w=3,color="blue"); 
    end;    
    if numba%10 == 1
        plot!([K[1],K[1],K[1]]+1.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],
            [K[3]-1,K[3]-1,K[3]-3]+2,w=3,color="blue"); 
    end;
    if numba%10 == 2
        plot!([K[1],K[1],K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],
            [K[3]-2,K[3]-2,K[3]-3]+2,w=3,color="blue");
        plot!([K[1],K[1],K[1]]+1.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],
            [K[3]-1,K[3]-1,K[3]-2]+2,w=3,color="blue");
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],
            [K[3],K[3],K[3]]-1,w=3,color="blue"); 
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],
            [K[3],K[3],K[3]],w=3,color="blue"); 
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],
            [K[3],K[3],K[3]]+1,w=3,color="blue"); 
    end;
    if numba%10 == 3
        plot!([K[1],K[1],K[1]]+1.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],
            [K[3]-1,K[3]-1,K[3]-3]+2,w=3,color="blue");
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],
            [K[3],K[3],K[3]]-1,w=3,color="blue"); 
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],
            [K[3],K[3],K[3]],w=3,color="blue"); 
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],
            [K[3],K[3],K[3]]+1,w=3,color="blue");
    end;    
    if numba%10 == 4
        plot!([K[1],K[1],K[1]]+1.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3]-1,K[3]-1,K[3]-3]+2,w=3,color="blue");
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3],K[3],K[3]],w=3,color="blue"); 
        plot!([K[1],K[1],K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3]-1,K[3]-1,K[3]-2]+2,w=3,color="blue");
    end;    
    if numba%10 == 5
        plot!([K[1],K[1],K[1]]+1.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3]-2,K[3]-2,K[3]-3]+2,w=3,color="blue");
        plot!([K[1],K[1],K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3]-1,K[3]-1,K[3]-2]+2,w=3,color="blue");
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3],K[3],K[3]]-1,w=3,color="blue");
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3],K[3],K[3]],w=3,color="blue"); 
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3],K[3],K[3]]+1,w=3,color="blue"); 
    end;
   if numba%10 == 6
        plot!([K[1],K[1],K[1]]+1.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3]-2,K[3]-2,K[3]-3]+2,w=3,color="blue"); 
        plot!([K[1],K[1],K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3]-1,K[3]-1,K[3]-3]+2,w=3,color="blue"); 
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3],K[3],K[3]]-1,w=3,color="blue"); 
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3],K[3],K[3]],w=3,color="blue"); 
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3],K[3],K[3]]+1,w=3,color="blue");
    end;    
    if numba%10 == 7
        plot!([K[1],K[1],K[1]]+1.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3]-1,K[3]-1,K[3]-3]+2,w=3,color="blue"); 
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3],K[3],K[3]]+1,w=3,color="blue"); 
    end;            
    if numba%10 == 8
        plot!([K[1],K[1],K[1]]+1.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3]-1,K[3]-1,K[3]-3]+2,w=3,color="blue");
        plot!([K[1],K[1],K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3]-1,K[3]-1,K[3]-3]+2,w=3,color="blue");
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3],K[3],K[3]]-1,w=3,color="blue"); 
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3],K[3],K[3]],w=3,color="blue"); 
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3],K[3],K[3]]+1,w=3,color="blue");
    end;    
     if numba%10 == 9
        plot!([K[1],K[1],K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3]-1,K[3]-1,K[3]-2]+2,w=3,color="blue");
        plot!([K[1],K[1],K[1]]+1.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3]-1,K[3]-1,K[3]-3]+2,w=3,color="blue"); 
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3],K[3],K[3]]-1,w=3,color="blue"); 
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3],K[3],K[3]],w=3,color="blue"); 
        plot!([K[1]+1,K[1]+1,K[1]]+0.25,[K[2],K[2],K[2]],[K[3],K[3],K[3]]+1,w=3,color="blue");
    end;    
end;
end; # END MODULE
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: There seem to be lots of ways to plot from one 3D point to another. Have you looked at the [documentation](https://juliaplots.github.io)? What have you tried?

Comment: In its current form, this question is unlikely to attract an answer. I would suggest re-writing it to something like this: "Using the Plots package, how can I draw a line between two co-ordinates in a 3-dimensional plot? Here is what I have tried so far: *code here demonstrating a serious attempt to solve the problem in a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) environment*".

Comment: `using Plots; plot((x, y, z), (x2, y2, z2))`